# Override Gem helper method in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, camaleon

I've a method called `cama_current_user` provided by a Gem [Camaleon CMS](https://github.com/owen2345/camaleon-cms) which is used all over inside the Gem. Now I'm using this Gem with my application where I need to override the method `cama_current_user'  by doing something like this,

```
  def cama_current_user
    @current_user
  end
```

I've added this method inside `ApplicationController`, `ApplicationHelper` and even added a new module like this,

```
module CamaleonCms::SessionHelper
  def cama_current_user
    @current_user
  end
end
```

but none of these methods are invoking during the execution. So How can I override the existing method definition provided by the Gem.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.Thank you !!

Comment: define the module under `config/initializers` folder

Comment: thanks but the variable I'm setting inside method is dynamic variable, and will be changed with user signin and signout.

Comment: it does not matter as long as `@current_user` is defined. Putting it into `initializers` will make sure Rails will load the code and use it it in the first place.

Comment: not working :(, I've added module inside `initializers` and added `binding.pry` inside it, but it is still not invoking.

Comment: restarted server?